# data-attribute wont submit content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter

I'm busy developing my first Twitter application. However, I'm stuck at something basic which I cant solve for some reason. I used to use data-attributes alot, but I just cant get it to work. It just wont submit the content of my data-attribute

**Part of my HTML.**

```
<div id="invTweet" class="_invitation-tweet-inner no-select" data-tweet="Here comes the content of the tweet which will be submitted">Here comes the content of the tweet</div>

<div id="post-invitation-tweet" class="button blue post-tweet">Post Tweet</div>
```

**Part of my Javascript**

```
    var tweet = $("#invTweet").attr("data-tweet");      
    $(document).on('click',"#post-invitation-tweet",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/db-requests/db-postInvitationTweet.php",
            data: {tweet:tweet},
            success: function(data){    finishInvitationTweet(data);    }
        });
    });

function finishInvitationTweet(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

I use alert(data) for debugging purposes. When I click on the Post Tweet button, an alert will open with the echo "Undefined index: tweet  emptyTweet". Look below for a snippet of my db-postInvitationTweet.php:

```
//Get Tweet data
$tweetMsg = safe($mysqli,$_POST['tweet']);

//Check if $tweetMsg is empty. No > post tweet.
if ($tweetMsg != '') {

$post_tweet = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetMsg));

if (187 == $connection->http_code) {
  echo "statusDuplicate";
  die();
}

if (!$post_tweet) {
    echo "tweetError";  
} else {
    //Update the invitation_sent column in database
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET invitation_tweet = '1' WHERE oauth = ? ") or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $access_token['oauth_token']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo "tweetSuccess";
}

} else {
    echo "emptyTweet";  
}
```

What am I missing :')

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Thanks for noticing. I changed the sources while I was making this post. I just updated my post. It's alerting 'emptyTweet' which can be found at the bottom of my db-postInvitationTweet.php. It somehow does not post the content of the tweet while I defined it..

Comment: What does a `console.log(tweet)` or `alert(tweet) show just after `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: there are some really basic debugging steps that should have been performed before this question was even asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using?  As of around version 1.4 the appropriate way to access a data attribute would be through the data() method, see method signature and docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

If you change that you may be able to get it to work just fine.  See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whRnD/) with working solution as proof of concept.

Changed

```
var tweet = $("#invTweet").attr("data-tweet");
```

To

```
var tweet = $("#invTweet").data("tweet");
```

Comment: either will work for strings. It's no different than reading any other attribute with exception that `data()` will return objects and arrays if applicable

Comment: @Dogoferis I'm using 1.10.2. Anyway, I've changed it to .data and it works perfectly fine now. Kinda weird though, as it was working fine yesterday.. 

Thanks! I'll soon accept your answer!